# CLR enabled Code + Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis, subquery, sqlclr

Whenever there is a subquery used to retrieve a column and if it returns more than 1 value an error occurs:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value

This has happend with one of our ssis package which was using a stored procedure which threw this error.

Somebody said us to explore if using CLR enabled code in SQL Server can we identify that due to which column or query this error has occured.

I haven't worked on CLR enabled SQL code yet. But when I got this kind of error SQL doesn't provide more details. We have to dig into the code and check what is causing the problem.

Is it possible that .net code (CLR enabled SQL) can give more details about error than it is giving while we are executing a stored procedure on SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The error is being reported by SQL Server so SQLCLR code would receive the exact same error message.

Your T-SQL code in the stored procedure should be in a TRY / CATCH and the CATCH block should be reporting the `ERROR_LINE ()` so that you can narrow it down.